# How to push all annotated tags?

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag

How do I push all annotated tags from my local repo to the remote, without pushing lightweight tags?

I use lightweight tags locally that I don't want pushed, so `git push --tags` is not a solution.

I am aware of `git push --follow-tags` but that will only push tags that are associated with commits currently being pushed.

I need this option because my normal workflow involves pushing from time to time, but only tagging when finalizing a release, and I sometimes forget to push a tag. This problem often goes undetected for a long time and causes a bit of confusion with other developers, since we become out of sync with our tags.

Since it's complicated to list which *annotated* tags exist locally but not remotely, I would like to solve this problem by just pushing all local annotated tags, which will ensure that all developers' local and remote repos have the same annotated tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not too difficult.  First find all *annotated* tags (by rejecting tags that point directly to commits rather than to annotated tag objects).  This is a bit long, so you might wish to write it as a shell function:

```
list_annotated_tags() {
    git for-each-ref --format '%(objecttype) %(refname)' refs/tags |
        while read reftype refname; do
            case $reftype in tag) echo $refname;; esac
        done
}
```

Read the output of the above and use them as refspec arguments to a `git push` command:

```
git push origin $(list_annotated_tags)
```

and your script is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that my lightweight tags don't include a `taggerdate`. In that case, this will work at the command line or in a script:

```
taglist=`git for-each-ref refs/tags --format '%(refname:short) %09 %(taggerdate:short)' | \
grep -E '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' | \
cut -f 1 | \
tr '\n' ' '`
```

followed by:

```
git push origin $taglist
```

*Command summary, for anyone who is interested*:

- 1st line - retrieves a `git for-each-ref` tag list, formatted to show the tagname, a tab, and the date. (Only annotated tags will have a date.)
- 2nd line - `grep` command searches through the 1st command's results, pulling only those tags with dates.
- 3rd line - `cut` command removes everything after the initial column (ie, from before the tab following each tagname to the `newline` ending each result line).
- 4th line - `tr` command replaces `newline` with a space in the end results. (The tagnames are now on one line, separated with spaces.)

The results are stored in a variable (`taglist` - note the backticks at the beginning and end of the entire command set following the `taglist=`).

Finally, then, you push the tag list to origin (using a `$` to indicate that `taglist` is a variable).